# Linking cells & sorting/filtering

Tags: excel

I have a file with 2 worksheets & 2 teams of people involved. Team #1 needs to complete their worksheet first. Once finished, team #2 takes over and has to complete their own worksheet in the file. Columns A & B will be identical for both worksheets, with team #1 filling in the information.

I have columns A & B for team #2 linked to auto-populate once team #1 fills the information in on their end (=Team1!A7:B7). My issue is that columns C:F are different between the 2 worksheets. If Team 1 changes the viewing order of their data by sorting/filter, this will change the order on Team 2's worksheet as well - but only for columns A & B. The remaining columns of data associated with columns A & B on Team 2's spreadsheet do not move when Team 1's data is rearranged. This now makes it not match up with the rest of the data in that row.

Is there a way to link an entire row of data on Team 2's spreadsheet, so that if one cell is relocated the entire rest of the row moves with it? Other than locking Team 1's sheet down and preventing any reordering of the data, I can't figure out how to make everything stay together in the row they belong in when only 2/6 columns are linked and moving.

Comment: Depending on how your sheets are formatted, you can use either `VLookup` or `Index` and `Match` for columns other than columns **A** and **B**. This will mean that the values displayed in columns other than **A** or **B** will always be synched. Saying that, VBA approach is probably more suited in this situation